# Unbinding preventDefault in click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll, nav

I'm currently encountering issues with a mobile navigation I have created. It's a simple hamburger icon and when you click it, it opens a fullscreen menu. The problem is I'm trying to disable scrolling when the overlay is visible. Now I figured I could achieve this by adding;

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

This works once, but when you close the menu again preventDefault remains active and I have no clue how to unbind this because the hamburger icon is used for both opening and closing the menu.

I have added the full js script I use below;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".icon").click(function () {
    $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()}); 
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  }); 
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to achieve, using `.on()` and `.off()` jQuery methods!

```
$(document).on('touchmove', 'body', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
$(document).off('touchmove', 'body', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

But there is also an `unbind()` function!

```
$('body').unbind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
```

Code example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var cancelScroll = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }

  $(".icon").click(function () {
    if ($(".mobilenav").is(":visible")) {
      $('body').unbind('touchmove', cancelScroll); 
    } else {
      $('body').bind('touchmove', cancelScroll); 
    }
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  }); 
});
```

**Note:** Returning `false` from a handler is equivalent to calling both `.preventDefault()` and `.stopPropagation()` on the event object.

so it could be just:

```
var cancelScroll = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: I'm aware of those functions, but I have to idea where to add them within my script. So I'm unsure where to unbind the prevent default.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I'm having the same issue as the other answer. The unbind part just isn't working.

Comment: Try to use .on() and .off() functions instead!

Comment: Instead of bind and unbind?

Comment: Ah. I remembered the issue why. You need to bind and unbind exactly the same function. But not the same-defined function. I mean - you need to put your function into a variable. I will update the answer in 1 min

Comment: Aha thanks for the fix, can you explain what the issue was with unbinding if I may ask?

Comment: When you pass a function() {...} as a parameter - new function in memory is created. Even if the second function has the same parameters and the same body - in javascript - it is a new function, as it is created in a new memory location. So you binded one function and tried to unbind another function - thats why this did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag to differentiate and unbind on close,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var isClose = false;
  $(".icon").click(function () {

    if(isClose){
      $('body').unbind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()}); 
      isClose = false;
    }else{
      $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault();});
      isClose = true; 
    }
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. I do get the idea of creating the variable though. I'm not that experienced with js, so I cant see where it goes wrong.

Comment: If you can add a fiddle, I can take a look.

Comment: The issue is on mobile, I can give you the link where it's hosted though? http://www.epicconcepts.nl

Comment: If you can share me link with the above code(answer), I can debug and tell you.

Comment: Ah I see the problem is fixed in the other answer, thanks for the help none the less.